# Including contacts that have done multiple activities in one search

Tags: database, activities

I'm trying to build a list of people who did one specific activity (which was send an email) that have done other activities as well (trying to find activists). How do I build this list?

Trying to work off of this search: https://crm.aclusocal.org/civicrm/contact/search/custom?_qf_Custom_display=true&qfKey=CRMContactControllerSearch4wcjzxp91r0g04sscgwg4g40080w00wgks88wksg0ogcoc0cw8_3758

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a Group for one of the criteria and then do a search via Search Builder for that Group and for the other Activity.

[image]